# Ubuntu not finding my LVM2 volume

Tags: lvm

first let me say that I'm pretty green when it comes to Ubuntu (and Linux in general) but using guides that I came across online I was able to setup a Ubuntu 13.10 media/file server using a spare PC and drives that I purchased new.

I joined my drives together in a LVM2 volume and things were great until the other night we had a power surge and now when booting the system I get these errors,

SATA5: Ultra DMA Mode-6, S.M.A.R.T. Capable but Command Failed Sec Master Hard Disk:S.M.A.R.T. Command Failed (my two other drives come up as Capable and Status OK)

Then when booting into Ubuntu itself I get this error message,
The disk drive for /media/######## is not ready yet or not present.

Is there anything that I can do to try to retrieve the data that was on this volume to get it off those drives and backed up, or should I start looking for new disk drives and coming to grips with loosing all my media?

Comment: I've never tried it, but in principle it's possible to recover data whose physical extents lie outside the damaged PV by activating the volume group in `partial` mode - see [Is It Possible To Recover A Partial LVM Logical Volume?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/219151/is-it-possible-to-recover-a-partial-lvm-logical-volume)